# Mac as a python development environment, parallel or no parrallel

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac, python

I’m planning on switching to Mac platform as my primary dev machine - I do python full stack development. I have had a MacBook Air for 5 years as a personal PC so I'm generally familiar with the OS.

After reading some articles ([including this one](http://www.fullstackpython.com/development-environments.html)), it looks like a lot of people, although using Mac OS X, installs Ubuntu in a virtual PC with Parallel Desktop and do the actual development there.

I’d like to keep my dev environment native if possible. Currently I use a Linux desktop and my productivity is pretty decent. The last thing I want is to switch to a good portable platform but my productivity drops considerably.

So is it hard/impossible to have a dev environment in native Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Python + Mac/OSX newbie. Here's my two cents - OSX is quite well supported for Python development. The trick is to first install Homebrew and then install the latest 2.7.x or 3.x versions of Python. I wouldn't bother with native installs of Python. After that, you shouldn't face any problems to develop, debug and test your application logic.

As far as IDEs go- PyCharm, Atom, Sublime Text, Vi, Emacs are all quite well supported on OSX

You will of course have to install ubuntu or your target linux deployment distro in a VM to debug production issues, there's no getting around that.